# SQL - Joining Table with out temp table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to join below tables and get the output as specified below in PostgreSQL. I am not able to able to do it in direct sql, is writing function and using temp table is the only possible solution or is there any other way to do it. Can you please suggest.

Table 1

```
Fruit  | Box
_____________
Apple  |   1
Apple  |  3
Orange |   2
Orange |  4
```

Table 2

```
Unit  |    Box
_______________
RU1   |     1
RU2   |     2
RU1   |     3
RU3   |     4
```

Output

```
Apple   |   RU1
Orange  |   RU2
Orange  |   RU4
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is a basic `join` with a `distinct`:

```
select distinct fruit, unit
from table1 t2 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.box = t2.box;
```

Comment: This is starting to get personal.  This is the second downvote on a valid answer today.